# How to get access token for vsts through api?

Tags: access-token, azure-devops-rest-api

I generate the access token for my account from the account security tab . Is there any way to get the access token via API call ??

Answer (score 1):

No such a API, the PAT will be displayed once you create it and this is **the ONLY time** the PAT will be displayed.

> Make sure you copy the token now. We don't store it and you won't be
>   able to see it again.

You will need to copy it and store it somewhere safe, so that you can retrieve it as needed.

You can [Revoke The PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=vsts#revoke-personal-access-tokens-to-remove-access) and create a new one, then replace with the new PAT

[image]

Comment: Yes I generated the token from the website but I was looking for generate the access token through API . Anyway thanks :)

Comment: @JoyBasak No such a API, just as the message mentioned "`Make sure you copy the token now. We don't store it and you won't be able to see it again.`" If you missed the token when generate it first time, then you cannot get it anymore.

Comment: @JoyBasak Is that answered your question? any update?